# Why cant i sum up all of my values (user values) problem with while?

Tags: python

I'm new to the coding world. I have a problem with adding up all of the users' input values, as I don't know how many there will be. Any suggestions?
This is how far I've gotten. Don't mind the foreign language.

```
import math
while(True):
    n=input("PERSONS WEIGHT?")
    people=0
    
    answer= input( "Do we continue adding people ? y/n")
    if answer == "y" :
        continue
    elif answer == "n" :
        break
    else:
        print("You typed something wrong , add another value ")
    people +=1
    limit=300
    if a > limit :
        print("Cant use the lift")
    else:
        print("Can use the lift")
```

Comment: you need to share your current code and explain the issue.

Comment: `cilveki=0` resets it back to 0 with each loop. Maybe you should have that outside of the loop.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to this. I've been stuck here for awhile.

Comment: Side note that a is not defined, assuming this is all your code.

Comment: `limit=300` could be moved outside of the loop.

Comment: a=(all of the users' inputs added up)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import math library for simple addition. Since you did not mention that what error are you getting, so I guess that you need a solution for your problem. Your code is too lengthy. I have write a code for you. which has just 6 lines. It will solve your problem.
Here is the code.

```
sum = 0;
while(True):
  n = int(input("Enter Number.? Press -1 for Exit: "))
  if n == -1:
    break
  sum = sum+n
print(sum)
```

**Explanation of the Code:**
First, I have declared the variable sum. I have write while loop, inside the while loop, I have prompt the user for entering number. If user will enter -1, this will stop the program. This program will keep on taking user input until unless user type "-1". In the end. It will print total sum.

**Output of the Code:**

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Here's something for you to learn from that I think does all that you want:

```
people = 0
a = 0

while True:

    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("PERSONS WEIGHT?"))
            break
        except ValueError as ex:
            print("You didn't type a number.  Try again")

    people += 1
    a += int(n)

    while True:
        answer = input("Do we continue adding people ? y/n")
        if answer in ["y", "n"]:
            break
        print("You typed something wrong , add another value ")

    if answer == 'n':
        break

limit = 300
if a > limit:
    print("Total weight is %d which exceeds %d so the lift is overloaded" % (a, limit))
else:
    print("Total weight is %d which does not exceed %d so the lift can be operated" % (a, limit))
```

The main idea that was added is that you have to have separate loops for each input, and then an outer loop for being able to enter multiple weights.

It was also important to move `people = 0` out of the loop so that it didn't keep getting reset back to `0`, and to initialize `a` in the same way.